# Python merge sort

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

In *Algorithms* Fourth Edition by Robert Sedgewick and Kevin Wayne, the exercise 2.2.10 states that:

> Implement a version of merge() that copies the second half of a[] to
>   aux[] in decreasing order and then does the merge back to a[]. This
>   change al- lows you to remove the code to test that each of the halves
>   has been exhausted from the inner loop.

This is my code in Python:

```
def merge(a, lo, mi, hi): 
    aux_hi = deque(a[mi:hi])
    for i in range(lo, hi)[::-1]：
        if aux_hi: 
            last_a = i-len(aux_hi)
            if last_a < lo: 
                a[i] = aux_hi.pop()
            else: 
                a[i] = aux_hi.pop() if aux_hi[-1] > a[last_a] else a[last_a]
        else: 
             break
```

Have I implemented it as required? Or can it be improved further?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need `deque()` as you are popping from the end / right side which is a \$O(1)\$ operation for regular lists:

```
aux_hi = a[mi:hi]
```

There are some minor concerns regarding:

- use of [whitespaces in the expressions and statements](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#whitespace-in-expressions-and-statements)

Comment: Yes, you are right. deepcopy(precisely shallow copy) is not necessary here.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I haven't tried to run your code nor the modifications I wrote.

**Being explicit**

Instead of using `[::-1]`, I'd recommend using `reversed` which is easier to read but more verbose.

Also, as you are already using `if/else` you could get rid of the ternary operator to write the more explicit:

```
        if last_a < lo:
            a[i] = aux_hi.pop()
        elif aux_hi[-1] > a[last_a]:
            a[i] = aux_hi.pop()
        else:
            a[i] = a[last_a]
```

which can be re-organised as:

```
        if (last_a < lo or aux_hi[-1] > a[last_a]):
            a[i] = aux_hi.pop()
        else:
            a[i] = a[last_a]
```